# emit event false trigger recursively inside in asynchronous validators-angular recative forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular9, angular-forms, formarray

I have using reactive form and form have 60 fields. so I have written asyncvalidtors for server-side validation.

**Note: Not using value changes mechanism.it works with below  two line**

```
   formGroup.ProductId.setErrors(null, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
     formGroup.ProductId.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent:false});
```

**Problem with Validators Mechanism**

I have faced an issue in the following scenarios. In async validators, I have use case if productName control is valid and set error null for productId fields.i have set the errors, and while perform updateValueandValidity send another request to the server .

```
if(result.controlName =='ProductName' && result.Validation==true){

// if control Name is productName // set Errors as Null for  Product ID

formGroup.ProductId.setErrors(null, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
 formGroup.ProductId.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
//But it recursively call  while perform this line


}
```

**validators**

```
 export class SomeAsyncValidator {
       static createValidator = (someService: SomeService) => (control: AbstractControl) =>
           timer(500)
               .pipe(
debounceTime(2000)
                // If previous query is different from current
                , distinctUntilChanged(),
                   map(() => control.value),
                   switchMap((name) => someService.exists({ request })),
                   map(() => ({
    
    if(result.controlName =='ProductName' && result.Validation==true){
    
    // if control Name is productName // set Errors as Null for  Product ID
    
    formGroup.ProductId.setErrors(null, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
     formGroup.ProductId.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
    //But it recursively call  while perform this line
    
    
    }
    
    })),
                   catchError(() => of(null)));
    }
```

Comment: maybe you can try to call  `updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true })`

Comment: sorry tried `{ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false }`forget to add in question updated

Comment: it works for value changes not for validators

Comment: okay then maybe try to add `distinctUntilChanged()` in the pipe

Comment: its already there debounce and distinctUntilChanged i have remove in question now updated

Comment: gona say your error is caused by calling `setErrors` manually while trying to use valdiators. you shouldn't be doing that, so this seems like a design problem. if your validation involves multiple fields, it should probably be a group validator. you should describe the actual problem you're trying to solve here so you can get help with your design.

Comment: @bryan60 thanx yes you are saying to use validators.compose  for group validators for the particular fields. for clarification have raised as  a StackOverflow question.